# Report Builder 3 Creating a current, 30, 60, date range parameter to generate reports

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, range, builder

I am new to Report Builder and I have been tasked with creating a date range search parameter. They are looking for current, 30 day, and 60 day values. The overall report is working and I have only made a few changes to it. So in parameters I made a dateRange parameter and set data type up as Date/Time and no boxes are check below. in the available values properties I have specified 3 values:

1. Current:   `=DateAdd("d", -1, Today())`
2. 30 day Range:   `=DateAdd("d", -30, Today())`
3. 60 day Range:   `=DateAdd("d", -60, Today())`

Default values and advanced properties have remained untouched.

Why did I go with those expressions? I was looking at the StartDate and EndDate values and the enddate value has `=DateAdd("d", -1, Today())` and so my logic said going back 30 and 60 days i would need add a neg in front. This I think is errant thinking. The customer is looking for the parameter to return the the values starting from the first day of the month so I need to make sure I use a month.minValue to have the report always start on the first day of the month. I hope all of this makes sense. Again I am very new to Report Builder so forgive me for my ignorance.

Jim

Comment: `=DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1)` this expression will give you the first date of current month. Explain in detail how you want to filter the data via parameter for further support.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro, I am tasked to make changes to a report, it is being used in SharePoint. Currently we have parameters setup as start date and end date, I want to add a new parameter that give a date range and I have the drop down box setup as:

Comment: Ok, you want report runs by default from first date of month to yesterday of current day, right? your 30 day range will produce startdate as: yesterday current date - 30 days, and 60 will produce startdate as: yesterday current date - 60 days in both cases enddate will be yesterday current day. If so confirm it to help you with an answer.

Comment: Current, 30 day, and 60 day. Say I want to get the data from the data source and I want the last 3 months worth of information the result will start at the first day of the first month, and end on the current date the report was ran.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: say i want a report for June to Sept, I need to have the report start on the first of the month, so 1 June and it will end on the day before the report is run.

Comment: Ok, so I am getting a little further on writing the parameter, here is what I am thinking so far: =DateSerial(Year(Now()), (3*DatePart("q", Now())) -2, 1) and this would be for a quarter, I need to change this from a quarter to 60 days instead of 90, so to do that would I change the 3*DatePart to 2*Datepart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and feedback comments, this is what I got.

Define `DateRange` parameter as follows:

Available values:

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, Today())
=DateAdd("d", -30, Today())
=DateAdd("d", -60, Today())
```

For use current `=DateAdd("d", -1, Today())` as default you must to put it in the default values tab of `DateRange` parameter.

Now for handle the end date I've created other parameter named `EndDate` set it default value to current:

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, Today())
```

Now in the dataset query you have to use the parameter `DateRange` to get the first date of month. Check this example.

```
select *
from mytable a
where a.DocDate between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateRange), 0)
and @EndDate
```

> `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateRange), 0)` will produce the first date of month based on the daterange selection example using
>   today date:

current: `01/10/2015` (dd/MM/yyy format)

30 days range: `01/09/2015`

60 days range: `01/08/2015`

`EndDate` parameter will produce `26/10/2015`

Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: Thank you @Alejandro, I believe this is what I needed, will check to make sure in a little while.

Comment: For my date range are the values I have listed: =DateAdd("d", -1, Today())
=DateAdd("d", -30, Today())
=DateAdd("d", -60, Today()) work for getting the right date range or is there a better way of writing this parameter?

Comment: It will produce the date of 1 day ago, 30 days ago or 60 days ago. Then the values are used to get the first date of the respective month in example: if you choose `30 days` today it will produce 26/09/2015 so the first date of the month will be 01/09/2015 as the startdate, the `endDate` will be 26/10/2015.

Comment: Nice, that is what I was looking for @Alejandro. I was just making sure my initial values for the date range are valid. This helped.